# Not Able To Download Bhav Zip File

Tags: vb.net, download, stock

Last Time this code is working but now i am not able to download the bhav file from the NSE web site

blow the code i am using

```
    Dim WC As New WebClient
    Dim DD, MMM, YYYY As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileURL As String
    Dim ZipPath As String

 
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        DD = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd")
        MMM = UCase(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMM"))
        YYYY = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy")

        If UCase(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dddd")) = "SATURDAY" Then Exit Sub
        If UCase(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dddd")) = "SUNDAY" Then Exit Sub

        FileName = "cm03AUG2021bhav.csv.zip"
        FileName = FileName.Replace("03AUG2021", DD & MMM & YYYY)

        FileURL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2023/JAN/cm02JAN2023bhav.csv.zip"
        
        FileURL = FileURL.Replace("2023", YYYY)
        FileURL = FileURL.Replace("JAN", MMM)
        FileURL = FileURL.Replace("02", DD)
       
        ZipPath = App.Dir.BhavPath & "\" & FileName
        WC.DownloadFile(FileURL, ZipPath)
```

i am trying to download the file but not downloading now

getting the error in vb.net

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

url - https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2023/JAN/cm02JAN2023bhav.csv.zip

getting error in google crome

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2023/JAN/cm02JAN2023bhav.csv.zip" on this server.
Reference #18.83e83217.1672846762.b1fb356

i am able to download from this link from google chrome

https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/all_daily_reports.htm

Comment: You need to debug your code properly and explain exactly what happens. You're effectively saying "it doesn't work" and that is never an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: Not considering for a second that your string replacement thing is just wrong (e.g., in `...JAN2023...` you're replacing `02` in the Year with something else; also highly redundant), what made you think that adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` was a good idea? No web service allows that protocol, TLS12 is commonly used, which is the default in most current Windows Systems (including updated Windows 7 installations) -- The site, most probably, uses cookies to limit access to resources to a Browser session -- WebClient is obsolete